# How to pick elements from both arrays so that the difference between the sum is the minimum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are 2 arrays where the length of both arrays are the same.

array A = set of non-negative integers

array B = set of non-positive integers

I must either select A[i] or B[i] for each index i and want to know the minimum of abs(sum).

> e.g
>
> example 1
>
> > A = {1,2,3,4} , B = {-1,-2,-3,-4}
> >
> > then the minimum of abs(sum) would be 0 by selecting 1, -2, -3 and 4. (-1, 2, 3, -4) also works.
>
> example 2
>
> > A = {1,1,1,3} , B = {0,0,0,-3}
> >
> > then the minimum of abs(sum) would be 0 by selecting 1,1,1 and -3.

I can only think of naive way of computing every possible combinations which takes exponential time. Could there be any better approach for this problem?

Comment: i think u need to select alternatively ... not A[i] or B[i] for each i. add constraint of n and range of value in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in `O(n * num_diffs)` time complexity by imagining that the bucket of negatives is just another bucket of positives we are trying to get as close to the other as possible.

JavaScript code (a `diff` is the difference created when placing an item one of the buckets):

```js
function f(A, B){
  let diffs = new Set();
  diffs.add(A[0]);
  diffs.add(-B[0]);
  
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    let newDiffs = new Set();
    for (d of [...diffs]){
      newDiffs.add(d + A[i]);
      newDiffs.add(Math.abs(d + B[i]));
    }
    diffs = newDiffs;
  }
  console.log(`Diffs: ${ [...diffs] }`); 
  return Math.min(...diffs);
}

var ABs = [
  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, -2, -3, -4]], // 0
  [[1, 1, 1, 3], [0, 0, 0, -3]] // 0
]

for (let [A, B] of ABs){
  console.log(`A: ${ A }`);
  console.log(`B: ${ B }`);
  console.log(`Result: ${ f(A, B) }`);
  console.log('');
}
```

Comment: Isn't num_diffs in worst case 2^n? Which is also exponential

Comment: @Tuto my understanding is that the number of differences would depend on the range the values can take.